# task in background even after activity is closed

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating photo sharing app...but my problem is when users clicks on upload  button I want the user to be directed to the newsfeed activity instead of staying there in upload activity...and it should start uploading news feed  activity ..like **Instagram and Facebook** does ...cause I don't want user to be wait in that upload activity ...I want them to enjoy **news feed** while uploading is going on in background ....and also I want to show the progress of the video... how can I do this ...should I do it in background ,I don't know please tell me I am new to this

**this is where upload**

```
     mUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            parse = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
            String description = mdescription.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "uploading the video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String category = selected;
            String links = mlinks.getText().toString();
            uploadNewVideo(getString(R.string.new_photo), description, VideoCount, category, parse, links);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            ((Activity) mContext).finish();
        }
    });
}

   public  void uploadNewVideo(String photoType, final String description, int count , final String category, final Uri imgUrl, final String links){
    Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: attemting to upload new photo");
    FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();
    if (parse == null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select image ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {

        StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
                .setContentType("video/mp4")
                .build();
        if (photoType.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.new_photo))) {
            Log.d(TAG, "uploadNewPhoto: uploading photo");
            String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            StorageReference storageReference = mStorageReference.child(filePaths.FIREBASE_VIDEO_STORAGE + "/" + user_id + "/videos" + (count + 1));
            UploadTask uploadTask = null;
            mcancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mStoragetask.cancel();
                }
            });
            // mStoragetask = uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(bytes);
            mStoragetask = uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(parse,metadata);
            mStoragetask = uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri firebaseUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                   // firebaseUrl.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "photo upload sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mFirebaseMethods.AddVideoToDatabase(description, firebaseUrl.toString(),category,links);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    ((Activity) mContext).finish();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: photo upload fail ");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Photo upload failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);


                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okk..please wait

Comment: this is my code

Comment: I can upload my video but I want to do that in background ...and progress should show in news feed activity

Comment: should do the upload progress in newsfeed activity

Comment: okk...please take a time and help me

Comment: yes...I don't want to show progress in upload activity it just for selecting photo ....I want to show progress in newsfeed activity